# Problems with references in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, assemblies

I added a class in WinForm named it `class2`. From that class I reference to a winform form class called `chessboard`..

Winform shows me a mistake/error and writes:

> The type or namespace name "`ChessBoard`" could not be found
>   are you missing using directive or an assembly reference?

What do i do.. I am in the same project

Comment: C# identifiers are case-sensitive. So what's the name of your class: `chessboard` (as you claim) or `ChessBoard` (as the error message claims)?

Comment: Something else: Does IntelliSense ever suggest the chessboard class to you once you start typing, let's say, `chess`? If yes, then you've probably a simple typo in your code. If no, it might help if you show us the declarations of these classes, including the namespaces they are in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is "ChessBoard" capitalized exactly as it's capitalized in its class definition?

Do you have the same

```
namespace Whatever_Namespace
{

}
```

declaration around both classes?

Answer (score 1):

are probably not all under the same namespace, verify that the namespace is the same for both classes.

Regards.